# "TASK MANAGER" process is taking over a single-user mode database. What is it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a duplicate of the question I asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436991/i-run-sp-who-on-the-database-and-there-is-a-task-manager-process-what-is-it), but I was advised, that someone here could have a better idea what is happening.

I have a sporadic problem, when upgrading SQL Server in a single-user mode, using .NET SqlConnection, some other application somehow logs into the database, while the SQL code is being executed, and kicks my process out. SqlConnection is not closed or disposed in any way. But some other application somehow ends up connected to the database and that kicks my connection out.

When I run sp_who, I could see that a process that took control of the database is Command="TASK MANAGER".

Anyone could tell me what is this process, what is it's purpose, and how in the world it could get into a database, which is in single-user mode, and there is an active connection?

Comment: Do you shut down SQL Agent during this process? The tasks named "TASK MANAGER" (with low spid numbers) are internal processes.

Comment: @JonSeigel no, I didn't. Are you saying SQL Agent is an actual process that runs TASK MANAGER?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. What I do know is that SQL Agent connects to the instance when it's running, and this can prevent you from logging in while the server is in single-user mode. I had that problem yesterday, and stopping SQL Agent fixed it.

Comment: Just to be clear, this isn't the same Task Manager that you use in Windows to view processes and system performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the mystery [finally got resolved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx):

> Before you set the database to SINGLE_USER, verify the
>   AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC option is set to OFF. When set to ON, the
>   background thread used to update statistics takes a connection against
>   the database, and you will be unable to access the database in
>   single-user mode.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same issue today, If you have not put your AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ASYNC OFF, you will not be able to enter your database, you can solve this by putting your database offline. Important to know is that you need to set your deadlock priority to high, otherwise you will be deadlocked out of the command. Use following commands to get out of SINGLE user mode

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

ALTER DATABASE [YourDBName] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Followed by

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

ALTER DATABASE [YourDBName] SET ONLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Followed by

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

ALTER DATABASE [YourDBName] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. However I found that the OFFLINE/ONLINE step was not required; the `SET MULTIUSER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` worked just by itself when `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH` was done first

Answer (score 6):

Stop the "system_health" extended events trace. It will be listed under

`SQL Server Management Studio`
`-> [ServerName]`
`-> Management`
`-> Extended Events`
`-> Right-Click on 'System_health'`
`-> Hit Stop Session`

Once the blocker are fixed, restart the session.

Comment: Although the other answer explains why this happens, this one explains how to resolve it.

Comment: Perfect resolution for me. It worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable SQL Agent 'before' starting single use mode. As the agent accout will grab the single user access. Remeber the single user is not you it the first user/process to connect.